# Игнорирование регистра букв в расширении при поиске файлов C#

Tags: c#, linux, .net, файлы, mono

Необходимо при поиске файлов игнорировать регистр в расширениях файлов, так как приложение работает по ОС Linux в среде  Mono. Как можно это сделать? Например: pdf, Pdf, pDf, PDF и тд... Поиск необходимо вести по всем директориям и субдиректориям.

Сейчас делаю так:

```
public ICollection<FileInfo> GetFileInfo()
    {
        var directories = new DirectoryInfo(MediaPath);
        var extensions = new[] {"*.pdf", "*.doc"};
        var files = extensions.SelectMany(ext => directories.GetFiles(ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories));

        return files.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: UperCase/LowCase использовать при проверке расширения файла.

Comment: а сейчас, как работает?

Comment: @JDo, извините, мне самому стало интересно - чем Вас не устраивает предложенный мной способ? В нем есть какие-то недостатки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае работы с Windows ничего в вашем коде менять не нужно, регистр и так игнорируется при поиске файлов.

Иначе:

```
var files = directories.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var res = extensions.SelectMany(ext => 
   files.Where(file => file.Name.EndsWith(ext, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: Может у него .net core / linux?

Comment: только Моно под Линуксом.

Comment: @yolosora приложение под Линуксом в моно среде. Там к сожалению как в Вин регистр не игнорируется.

Comment: Извините, могу ошибаться, но кажется, что `f.EndsWith(...)` следует заменить на `file.Name.EndsWith(...)`.

Comment: @isnullxbh да, не заметил при оформлении

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(MediaPath);
var ext = new[] {".pdf", ".doc"};
var res = dir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
             .Where(f => ext.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower()))
             .ToArray();
```

Env.: macOS, .NET Core 2.2